# How to periodically check until ajax return status values have changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i checkstatus of ajax response to wait and check that it has changed from 200 -->500 -->200?
it has to be checked and recheck. Mine isnt working correctly here my code below.
NoTe: On succesfull form submission it will always be 200 .. so it need to check and recheck for 500 and then for 200 before redirecting to the mainpage again.

I tried to create checkstatus function so i can resuse. how can this be done correctly?

```
        // setTimeout(function() { location.reload(true);}, 3000);
     function checkStatus() {
            /***  Re check bit ***/
            var restartCheck = window.setInterval(
            $.ajax({
                // dataType : 'jsonp',
                //jsonp : 'js',
                url: "../../../../../rest/configuration",
                beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                    console.info('in beforeSend');
                    console.log(jqXHR, settings);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(" 500 top data still loading " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                    console.info('in error');
                    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert(" complete " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus);
                    console.info('in complete');
                    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    window.clearInterval(restartCheck);
                    alert(" success " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus);
                    console.info('in success');
                    console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
                }
            }), 3000); //This will call the ajax function every 3 seconds until the clearInterval function is called in the success callback.
            /*** recheck bit **/

}
```

/**
On initial success form submission the success values is 200.
After that I need to wait sometimes to check and recheck for 500 for server starts, when the Server restarts or is restarting it gives a 500 internal server message, it take about 30 to 40 sec or more to restart the server so i have await time for 30 sec.. Once the server restarts it gives a 200 success server message. and then redirect the page . SO i am trying to checkstatus until it changes from 200 --> 500 -200 
**/

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "foo.json",
        data: json_data,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log(xhr.status);
            alert("Your changes are being submitted: " + textStatus + " : " + xhr.status);
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('#myModal-loading').modal('show');

            //call function checkstatus  not currently workign
            //statsu val ==200 server inital form success val from server
            setTimeout(function () {
              count=0;
             var statusval = checkStatus();
            while(statusval == 200 and count <=5) {
               statusval = checkStatus();
 //statsu val has changed to 500 server is restarting

               if (statusval==500) {
               //wait for   30 sec to recheck if the server has restarted and changed to success ie 200 
                setTimeout(function () { checkStatus();}, 30000);
               }

             count++;
            }, 3000);

            alert("restartCheck " + restartCheck)
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload(true);
            }, 3000);
            // $('#myModal-loading').modal('hide');
            $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>').insertBefore('#myform');
            //location.reload(true);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // alert("Warning and error has occured: "+errorThrown + " : " + jqXHR.status);
            alert(jqXHR.responseText + " - " + errorThrown + " : " + jqXHR.status);

        }
    });

    });
    });
```

Comment: If it has a 500 error, it will never enter the success function, correct?

Comment: for success form submission, the server will always give a 200 message. so Then we have wait an recheck until we get 500 error messagefrom the server that its restarting using statuscheck. We have to wait recheck using statuscheck to see it has change to 200 after serverreboot before i redirct back to the main page.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I follow now. I'll post a snippet for you in a sec..

Comment: It would be worth your time to run your code through a linter (http://www.jslint.com/), there are a lot of errors in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anderslyman/dHxgB/) a try.

HTML:

```
<div></div>​
```

Code:

```
function waitForStatus(url, status, maxRetries, success, failure) {
    var count = 0;
    var restartCheck = setInterval(function() {
        count++;
        if (count <= maxRetries) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == status) {
                        clearInterval(restartCheck);
                        success(status);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            clearInterval(restartCheck);
            failure();
        }
    }, 3000);
}

var successCallback = function(status) { 
    $("div").append('<p>SUCCESS: returned ' + status + '</p>');
}; 

var failureCallback = function() {
    $("div").append('<p>FAILURE: max attempts reached</p>');
};

// This will succeed    
waitForStatus('/echo/xml', 200, 5, successCallback, failureCallback);

// This will fail
waitForStatus('/echo/xml/404', 200, 5, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

Comment: thanks you. quick question, how are you getting "/echo/xml"  and "/echo/xml/404" i will be passing just urllink to json file foo.json. 2nd if i just call function(status) or function wll they return the values"successCallback" and "failureCallback" or I would need to do something more to get those values?

Comment: Obviously I can't use your links because I don't have access to your server - "/echo/xml" and /echo/xml/404" happens to work for jsfiddle.net.

Comment: As to the latter, you should really study up on callbacks and how asynchronous code works, this isn't the time or place to explain that.  I would recommend `JavaScript: The Good Parts` by `Douglas Crockford`